# Get the Error Message from Request in Django

Tags: python, django, http-status-code-403

I attempted to raise a 403 error if the user accesses a page he is not allowed to access. In my **views.py**

```
def staff_room(request):
  user = request.user
  role = School.objects.get(user=user)
  if not role.is_teacher:
    raise PermissionDenied("Get out of the staff room!")
def library(request):
  user = request.user
  role = School.objects.get(user=user)
  if not role.is_librarian:
    raise PermissionDenied("Get out of the library!")
```

In my **403.html**, I want to retrieve the different messages thrown by the errors. Is there a way to do so? Something like `{{ exception.message }}` like say

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
You are not allowed to enter this room. {{ exception.message}}
```

Answer (score 3):

Django documentations tells us that for 403 errors it passes exception in the context like this

```
return http.HttpResponseForbidden(
    template.render(request=request, context={'exception': force_text(exception)})
)
```

So it seems that you should be able to just use `{{ exception }}` to access the exception's message. Otherwise you can override default 403 view and pass exception's message (or even format it) manually.